# Keypress event in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, events, keypress, keydown

I'm currently using `GetAsyncKeyState()` to detect Keydown events, but then the events will be repeated while you are holding down the key.

What would be an easy way to stop the event from repeating?

**Example**

If I hold down the key `i` on my keyboard for a while, I will get an output like this:

```
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

Instead of this:

```
i
```

I want to force the user to press the key again to trigger the event.

Comment: You need a window. They get posted to your thread's message queue and then dispatched to your window's window procedure.

Comment: @David: I don't really understand what you mean. I am using a console application. I'm not sure whether I have a window procedure. I'm sorry, I'm quite new to C++.

Comment: You don't generally want to detect keypresses in a console app. Why didn't you say that's what you are doing. Nowhere in your Q does it mention that you have a console app.

Comment: It wasn't a joke. This has to do with the way Windows interprets input from your keyboard. It doesn't have anything to do with your C++ application. It will do the same thing in *all* of your applications.

Comment: @David: Actually I'm not sure, but I am using a template. It actually opens a console window when it starts and then opens a window after it. It uses OpenGL.

Comment: @Code Grey: I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. Forgive me, I'm new. The example is actually a little bit different from what I really want to do. I have small game and when the player presses for example the right arrow key, it the character will keep moving. But I want the character to just move one step for each time the player presses a key. I thought I wouldn't need to explain all that, because it would be the same for all situations.

Comment: @Datox It's Cody not Code. Anyway, if you want good help, you should explain more about your problem. I think you would do well to edit your question to explain in detail what you are doing and what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks David. He's also right: if you *do* need a way to handle this programmatically, you'll need to give us more information about the type of application that you've created. I don't know what the hybrid console/window app that you describe looks like. Showing more of your code might be helpful, particularly in your `main` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using a keyboard related message like WM_KEYDOWN or WM_CHAR to detect a key, Windows repeats WM_KEYDOWN when the user holds it down.  You simply need a your own bool flag that keeps track of the state of the key.  Only change your game object state when you see a difference between the state as reported by GetAsyncKeyState() and this flag.  Roughly:

```
bool movingLeft = false;
...
if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) < 0) != movingLeft) {
    movingLeft = !movingLeft;
    gameObject->setVelocity(movingLeft ? -10 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain how it works? I don't quite understand the return value of GetAsyncKeyState.

Comment: Return value of what?  GetAsyncKeyState returns a negative value if the key is down.

Comment: Sorry, I mean of GetAsyncKeyState. So, how do you determine that the event won't be executed if the player holds the key down?

Comment: Could you please help me a understanding a little bit better?

Comment: Not sure how to explain it better.  It returns a SHORT, the most significant bit is set when the key is down.  That's the sign bit.  Which makes the return value negative if the key is down.  Best way to get ahead is to actually try it.

Answer (score 1):

Use KeyPress events (or KeyUp).

Btw according to MSDN [SHORT WINAPI GetAsyncKeyState(__in  int vKey);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Determines whether a key is up or down
>   at the time the function is called,
>   and whether the key was pressed after
>   a previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

It doesn't say anything about detecting a keydown event.